# Проблемы с заголовком php

Tags: php, регистрация

Привет, мир! Вот делал как на видео уроке, и все равно где-то ошибся раз выводит вот такую ошибку:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at Z:\home\dimmetrius.name\www\includes\overall\header.php:3) in Z:\home\dimmetrius.name\www\register.php on line 52

Итак, вот что получилось:

```
if(isset($_GET['success']) && empty($_GET['success'])) {
    echo 'Регистрация успешно завершена';
} else {
    if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $register_data = array(
            'username'      => $_POST['username'],
            'password'      => $_POST['password'],
            'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'],
            'email'         => $_POST['email']
        );

        register_user($register_data);
        header('Location: register.php?success');
        exit();

    } else if(empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
}
```

Где, `header('Location: register.php?success');` все вроде написано правильно, но где-то заголовок стартует! Вот с-но и файл, `includes\overall\header.php`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <?php include 'includes/head.php'; ?>
    <body>
        <?php include 'includes/header.php'; ?>
        <div id="container">
            <?php include 'includes/aside.php'; ?>
```

Может я слеп, но здесь никакого заголовка не вижу!

Вот функция, register_user($register_data); которая регистрирует пользователей:

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}
```

Вот, array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');

```
function array_sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}
```

Где же может быть ошибка?

Comment: Поставил вместо 
header(); 

Яваскрипт
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.location.replace("register.php?success");</script>';

У яваскрипта все нормально работает, но почему header(); не хочет работать?И выдает неприятную ошибку, если лишних пробелов я не ставил и лишних символов тоже. Все написано в кодировке utf-8 (без BOM).

У кого-то есть соображения по этому поводу?

Comment: Заголовки необходимо отправлять до первой команды вывода. Первая команда вывода у Вас - `<!doctype html>`. Читайте документацию внимательнее.